# Rename multiple files with index id

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying create a `.bat` file which renames all items in a folder to a custom name with `index id`, from this:

```
abc.mp4
def.mp4
ghi.mp4
jkl.mp4
mno.mp4
pqr.mp4
```

to `{random numbers}` + `{predefined word}` + `{index id}`, as below:

```
14878845file1
48785556file2
22665887file3
47990456file4
...
```

Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "i=1"
SET "temp=file"
FOR %%A IN (*.mp4) DO CALL :SUB "%%A"
    :SUB
    IF %i% GTR 0 REN %1 "%i%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%temp%temp%ep%i%".mp4
    SET/A i+=1
```

This code above works perfectly, but in some cases still not working properly, sometimes it jumps the first file, or rename the same file twice with a different `index id`, or the `index id` would be another.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: If you rename a file that is then further down in alphabetic order the file will get picked up again by the `FOR` command.  You need to change to a `FOR /F` command and use the `DIR` command within the `IN` clause. `FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /a-d /b *.mp4') DO ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues with your code.

1) If you rename a file that is then further down in alphabetic order the file will get picked up again by the FOR command. You need to change to a FOR /F command and use the DIR command within the IN clause.

2) You would have also needed a `GOTO :EOF` after your `FOR` command otherwise the `:SUB` code will execute twice.

I have moved all of your code inside the `FOR` command and used delayed expansion accordingly.  I did not see any point in check if the variable was greater than zero when you already have it set to 1.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "i=1"
SET "temp=file"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /a-d /b *.mp4') DO (
    REN "%%A" "!i!!RANDOM!!RANDOM!temp%temp%ep!i!.mp4"
    SET /A i+=1
)
```

Comment: Additional to the above, @PetrKann, please take extreme care overwriting a System Variable, _(`%temp%`)_. I'd suggest you choose something else instead.